# Javascript - Not executing when used with C# Response.Redirect()

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, response

I have a user control with a button on it, on button click i want execute a `Javascript` pop up using the `ScriptManager` and return to the parent page to do a response.redirect. But for some reason my `Javascript` is not getting executed. I have noticed that if i remove the response redirect on the parent the `Javascript` execution works fine.

Below is my code:

UserControl:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace RegisterDemo
{
    public partial class RegisterUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {

        public delegate void customHandler(object handler);
        public event customHandler SendtoParent;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void usercontrolbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "validator", "alert('Error');", true);
            SendtoParent(sender); 

        }
    }
}
```

Parent Page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace RegisterDemo
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyUserInfoBoxControl.SendtoParent += new RegisterUserControl.customHandler(onusercontrolevent_click);
        }

        protected void DemoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "validator", "alert('u click this button');", true);
        }

        protected void onusercontrolevent_click(object sender)
        {

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.Page.GetType(), "event", "alert('event completed');", true);
            Response.Redirect("www.google.com");
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me find out how to get the `Javascript` in my `UserControl` to execute? What am i missing here?

Comment: you can't do that - the redirect is happening first

Comment: i understood that, but my question why is the javascript statement in the usercontrol not executing? this one : ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "validator", "alert('Error');", true);

Answer (score 0):

You can do the redirect with JavaScript. For example, `window.location.href = ""` instead of using `Response.Redirect` from the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the others your redirect is happening first. You can use either of the following to JS methods for redirection

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://google.com");

// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://google.com";
```

Create a new function

```
function Validation() {
    alert('Error');

    // similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
    window.location.replace("http://google.com");

    // similar behavior as clicking on a link
    window.location.href = "http://google.com";

}
```

and change you `ScriptManager`

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "validator", "Validation();", true);
```

Comment: i understood that, but my question why is the javascript statement in the usercontrol not executing? this one : ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "validator", "alert('Error');", true);

Comment: Because that piece of code runs on the client, it just jumps over it and runs the SendtoParent(sender); before the alert even runs.